# Second subversion pre-commit hook not working

Tags: bash, svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit

I am trying to add a second pre-commit script and it seems not to be catching when I place it in the hook.

The first script basically locks a file from being editing. The second script look at a path and compares a string value to a file that is being committed and if it matches then it will error.

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
GREP=/bin/grep
SED=/bin/sed
AWK=/usr/bin/awk
SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook
AUTHOR=`$SVNLOOK author -t "$TXN" "$REPOS"`

if [ "$AUTHOR" == "testuser" ]; then
exit 0
fi
if [ "$AUTHOR" == "" ]; then
exit 0
fi

CHANGED=`$SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | $GREP "^[U|A]" | $AWK '{print $2}'`
COMPARE=`$SVNLOOK diff -t "$TXN" "$REPOS"`
#Operation 001 Beginning
#Restrict users from commiting against testfile
for PATH in $CHANGED
do

if [[ "$PATH" == *path/to/file/testfile.txt ]]; then

    #allow testuser to have universal commit permissions in this path.
    if [ "$AUTHOR" == "testuser" ]; then
        exit 0
    else
        #User is trying to modify testfile.txt
         echo "Only testuser can edit testfile.txt." 1>&2
         exit 1
    fi
fi

done
#Operation 001 Completed

#Operation 002 Beginning
#Restrict commits based on string found in file
for PATH in $COMPARE
do

if [[ "$PATH" == *path/to/look/at/only/* ]]; then

$SVNLOOK diff -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | egrep 'string1|string2|string3' > /dev/null && { echo "Cannot commit using string1, string2 or string3 in files trying to commit" 1>&2; exit 1; }
else exit 0;

fi
done
#Operation 002 Completed
```

It keeps successfully committing the file even though the string is present. Any ideas why it wouldn't be catching it?

Comment: What do you mean *second* hook? You can use only *one* pre-commit hook.

Comment: Sorry my writing is poor. I have one hook but want to add a second script in addition to the one that is already in the hook and verified working.

Comment: Oh, understand :)

Comment: What is your `/bin/sh`? The `[[` is a bashism, so maybe doesn't work with `/bin/sh`. And doesn't good idea to use `PATH` variable as a temporary variable (in for loops). And IMHO the `*path/to/file/testfile.txt` doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first test:

```
if [ "$AUTHOR" == "testuser" ]; then
exit 0
fi
```

It causes an abort (with zero exit value) if the AUTHOR is `testuser`!

So your second test:

```
 if [ "$AUTHOR" == "testuser" ]; then
        exit 0
 else
        #User is trying to modify testfile.txt
         echo "Only testuser can edit testfile.txt." 1>&2
         exit 1
 fi
```

It's unnecessary because at this point the AUTHOR isn't `testuser`!

And maybe would better instead of your for-loop:

```
if $SVNLOOK changed -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | $GREP "^[U|A]" | $AWK '{print $2}' | grep -q 'path/to/file/testfile.txt'; then
  echo "Only testuser can edit testfile.txt." 1>&2
  exit 1
fi
```

The `if [[ "$PATH" == *path/to/file/testfile.txt ]]; then` test doesn't work because this test doesn't understand shell variables (and would better enclose between quotation marks because of `*`).

And I would replace the

```
for PATH in $COMPARE
do

if [[ "$PATH" == *path/to/look/at/only/* ]]; then
```

part to

```
if echo ${COMPARE} | grep -q "path/to/look/at/only"; then
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm going to play around with it and see if i can get it to flag the string values now if they edit a file in that location. thank you!

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Just a brief test but it seems to be working. I will have to do more extensive testing but I got it for the most part. Thank you so much.


       if echo ${COMPARE} | grep -q "path/to/file"; then
                if echo ${COMPARE} | egrep "string1"; then
                        echo "file contains string1" 1>&2
                        exit 1
                else
        exit 0
                fi
        fi